# Check if user is returning visitor (e.g.) from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'd like to know if its possible to check out if, for an example, user is returning one or if user visited before and completed a goal in the last three months?

The whole idea would be something like this:

1. User visits a page
2. Javascript API checks with GA
3. If true, execute the next: alert("Welcome back!");

So I don't want to get data like total number of visitors in the last few months from Google or something like that. I'd like to get data for specific user.

Preferred language is JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the GA documentation to determine if the API allows you to retrieve something like this?

Comment: I haven't found anything like this. If they don't allow this then the solution will be to create my own tracking app, and that's too much work.

Comment: I could not figure out a way to do this a few weeks ago, so I just created a user object in JavaScript and pushed data to it, then stored in my own cookie. Now when users trigger an event, I just add my own function after the ```ga('send', 'event', ...)``` function. Not sure if you're planning on doing anything crazy with it, but it wasn't too hard to set up.

Answer (score 1):

For any practical purpose, no.

If you try and do this via the API (you would have to store the client id as a custom dimension so you can query the current user) you will run into the API limits pretty soon, that's 10 000 requests per view and day (you may try on a smaller site, but even then you should cache the result from the API request for each visit to avoid issues with the quota). And you cannot do it purely in Javascript since you need to authenticate against your Analytics account, and if you do that purely in JS you would have to give each website user read access to your account (and they would actively need to log in to your account). You can however (AFAIK, i haven't yet done this) use a service account to generate an access token and use this in a javascript app.

Plus data might be not processed immediately, so if recurring visits happen within hours they will not be recognized as returning visits since the data is not yet available (in larger sites data processing takes up to 24 hours).

To avoid the first issue you could bulk download the data from GA and store it in a local database, but at that point you might as well skip the GA requirement completely (which would also solve the second issue) and simply use your own database.